# Computer turns on by itself

Tags: windows-7, sleep

I have a really strange problem here. I have a Asus Zenbook Prime running Windows 7. Whenever I put it to sleep and I have Pandora open (but paused) in my web browser, several hours later the computer turns itself back on and Pandora will unpause itself and start playing. (More often than not this happens at 3AM in the morning so I am less than pleased.)

What the heck is going on here? I've never even heard of this happening before...

Comment: Check the settings for Windows Update. It might be causing this.

Comment: oooh. It has my updates automatically installing at 3AM. Is this my problem?

Comment: Could be, did you check?

Comment: Woops. Didn't mean that to be a question but rather a statement. ;)

Comment: Could also be a problem with [Media Center updating](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979878). Run `powercfg -lastwake` from the command line to see if you can determine the culprit. Else you can [check the event log for wake events](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/179257-wake-source-read-event-viewer-log.html).

Comment: I'm gonna see if it happens again tonight after I disabled windows update...

Comment: It looks like Windows Update is the culprit in your case (and many others’ as well), so you should post that as an answer and accept it to close his question out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem in buckets (though without the music) with my Vaio laptop (Vista).  Turned out that there were about six different scheduled tasks (see Admin Tools ->Task Scheduler) that all requested "Wake the computer to run this task" (see "Conditions"), some every ten minutes or so.  These were things like "Adobe Flash update".

I deleted some, changed others to not wake from sleep (and to not run when on battery), and the box has been much better behaved (no longer starting up while inside my laptop case).

Answer (score 1):

First I would check in your BIOS to see if you have a `wake on alarm` timer set.  Some computers allow this and it can wake the computer at a specific time of day.

Second, I would check to see if the computer is set to go into hibernation after a set amount of time in sleep.  It may be waking the computer to go into hibernation and Pandora is interfering with it.

You may also want to reference [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproinstall/thread/da497f72-0575-4a97-a12b-bfad43f50182) to see how you can check what is waking the computer and possibly disable it.

Some relevant info from that site:

> Run the following command to show all the devices that can wake up the
>   computer from Sleep mode.
>
> > `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed`